# Converting html tag into text in android

Tags: android, html

I am developing android app.

In my app i retrieve the data from the database which is stored in the html format. For converting the html code into plain text i use `HTML.fromHtml(String)` . It convert the html code but it to convert `<font> color="######">some String</font>`.

Please help me if any one have any idea.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *It convert the html code but it will not convert.* Convert what or to what?

Comment: Actually it not allow me to write html code here in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Html.fromHtml(String) supports only few tags.
Check here,
http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html